# How to calculate 1D power spectrum from 2D noise power spectrum by radial averaging

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, noise

guys I am trying to calculate 1D power spectrum from 2D FFT of the image. I did it with horizontal averaging but by looking at a graph it's not making me sense. Can you please suggest how to do radial averaging over 2D data set to reach 1D representation of noise power spectrum. Thank you 
I will appreciate your help.

Here is my code
$

```
 fid = fopen('C:\Users\3772khobrap\Desktop\project  related\NPS_cal_data_UB\100000006.raw','r');
img = fread(fid,[512 512],'uint16');
roi = zeros(64);
avg = zeros(64);
Ux= 0.0075;% Pixel size
Uy = 0.0075;% Pixel size
%% This block of code is subdividing imaage into smaller ROI and averaging purpose
for r = 1:8 
    r_shift = (r-1)*64;
    for c = 1:8 
        c_shift = (c-1)*64;
        for i = 1:64 
            for j = 1:64
                p = img(i+r_shift,j+c_shift);
                roi(i,j) = p;
            end
        end
        avg = avg+roi;
    end
end
avg = avg./64;
%%Actual process of NPS calculation
scale = (Ux*Uy)./(64*64);%Scaling fator as per NPS calculation formula
f_x = 1/(2*Ux);%Nyquiest frequecy along x direction
f_y = 1/(2*Ux);%Nyquiest frequecy along y direction
FFT_2d = (fftshift(fft2(avg))).^2;% Power spectrum calculation
NPS = abs(FFT_2d).*scale; %% 2D NPS 
f = linspace(-f_x,f_y,64);% x-axis  vector for 1D NPS 
X_img = linspace(-f_x,f_x,512);% X axis of NPS image
Y_img = linspace(-f_x,f_x,512);% Y axis of NPS image

figure(1)
subplot(2,2,1)
imagesc(X_img,Y_img,img)
colormap gray
xlabel('X [cm]'); ylabel('Y [cm]')
title('noise image')
subplot(2,2,2)
imagesc(f,f,log(NPS))
colormap gray
xlabel('frequency [cm^{-1}]'); ylabel('frequency [cm^{-1}]');
title('2D NPS')
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(f_p,NPS(:,32))
xlabel('frequency [cm^{-2}]'); ylabel('NPS [cm^{-2}]')
title('1D NPS from central slice')
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(f_p,mean(NPS,2))
xlabel('frequency [cm^{-2}]'); ylabel('NPS [cm^2]')
title('1D NPS along X direction')
```

Comment: I don't get it.  How are you supposed to get a 1D power spectrum out of a 2D signal?  Horizontal averaging wouldn't make sense because you could have intensity profiles per row that are significantly different, so averaging wouldn't adequately capture the behaviour.

Comment: google search returned [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/34982) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23636-radially-averaged-power-spectrum-of-2d-real-valued-matrix). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @rayreng, I guess the idea is that one does not want to distinguish between frequency components that are just differently oriented, but have the same spatial frequency or wave number, so a spectrum over |k| = sqrt(k1^2 + k2^2).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.@rayryeng and A.Donda. Assuming the the Fourier transform of object symmetric we can interpolate over radial grid and for every radius we can count the amount of hits. Avergae of for all radius will give us the 1D power spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

You can program a function like this :

```
function profile = radialAverage(IMG, cx, cy, w)
    % computes the radial average of the image IMG around the cx,cy point
    % w is the vector of radii starting from zero
    [a,b] = size(IMG);
    [X, Y] = meshgrid( (1:a)-cx, (1:b)-cy);
    R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2);
    profile = [];
    for i = w % radius of the circle
        mask = (i-1<R & R<i+1); % smooth 1 px around the radius
        values = (1-abs(R(mask)-i)) .* double(IMG(mask)); % smooth based on distance to ring
        % values = IMG(mask); % without smooth
        profile(end+1) = mean( values(:) );
    end
end
```